# Flutter Installation problem on MacOS M1(13.4) Ventura | Cocoapods installation error

Tags: flutter, dart, installation, cocoapods

I downloaded flutter_macos_arm64_3.13.9-stable and Xcode 14.3.1 (1 4 E 300 c). I have fulfilled all the conditions that are on the flutter website. But there was a problem when I wanted to install COCOAPODS

I wrote in terminal `sudo gem install cocoapods`:

```
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    There are no versions of cocoapods-downloader (>= 2.0) compatible with your Ruby & RubyGems. Maybe try installing an older version of the gem you're looking for?
    cocoapods-downloader requires Ruby version >= 2.7.4. The current ruby version is 2.6.10.210.
```

Should I install an old version of XCode?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: any fixes to this problem? I'm facing the same

Comment: me to facing same issue, please give me any fixes for this